# Received "" Error when running the below c# code

Tags: c#

I get an error when running the following code. When the program comes to the `workbook2 != null` line of code, it crashes.

Error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80010108): The object invoked has disconnected from its clients. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010108 (RPC_E_DISCONNECTED))
>
> at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook.Close(Object SaveChanges, Object Filename, Object RouteWorkbook)

Code:

```
public void CompleteAuto()
{
        if (workbook1 != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("workbook1 is closed");
            workbook1.Close(false);
        }

        if (workbook2 != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("workbook2is closed");
            workbook2.Close(false);
        }

        if (workbook3 != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("workbook3 is closed");
            workbook3.Close(false);                
        }

        if (workbook4 != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("workbook4 is closed");
            workbook4.Close(false);                
        }

        if (workbook5 != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("workbook5 is closed");
            workbook5.Close(false);
        }

        if (workbook6 != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("workbook6 is closed");
            workbook6.Close(false);
        }

        if (workbook7 != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("workbook7 is closed"); 
            workbook7.Close(false);
        }

        if (workbook8 != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("workbook8 is closed");
            workbook8.Close(false);
        }

        if (stepByStep == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Step by Step done!");
            loadingForm.Hide();
        }

        MessageBox.Show("Output successful!");
        this.Close();
}
```

I am new to c# so I don't know if the above code is right or wrong. I just want to multiple if to check if the workbooks had been open. If yes then closed them, if no then the program keep running.

Could anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: We have no idea what your variables are or how they were initialized. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Can you edit your question and show us what "workbooks" are and how you initialize them?

Comment: I use 
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; 
Excel.Application xlApp;
Excel.Workbook workbook1;

But in the previous steps, some workbooks might be closed, but actually which one I don't know. So this function is to check is the above workbook still open, use this function to close them.

Comment: a `workbook2.Close(...);` does not set `workbook2` to `null`, neither does closing that workbook by hand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess, as your example is incomplete...

When you close the Workbook, you are not setting it to null.
Add
Workbook1= null;
after Workbook1.Close.

Same for all the other closures.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Thanks Bob, you give me the hints and I solved. I add workbook1 = null; and the following code follow this, it works, thanks a lot!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a function, which checks if your workbook is opened.
If it is not, it throws. It is not ideal, but it works.

```
public static IsOpened(Excel.Application currentApp, string workbook)  
{
    try
    {
        var item = currentApp.WorkBooks.get_item(workbook);
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
         return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Radek for your help. However, I saw this answer from the web and tried but I cannot find ```.get_item``` in c#.

Answer (score 0):

From Bob's answer, I successfully solved my question.

Here is my code:

```
if (workbook1 != null)
        {
            workbook1.Close(false);
            workbook1 = null;
        }
```

And guess what, it works!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered wrapping the code in a using statement? You indicate that you are new to C# so this might be more than you want to learn to fix this, since you will have to make your class implement IDisposable, but maybe this will help someone else. If you are using a recent version of Visual Studio, either 2019 or 2022 you can simple add the implementation and the Intellisense will practically walk you through the process.
In brief, what this does is automatically close and release any objects defined inside the using statement. Look it up--it is worth learning if you are going to continue using C#.

Comment: It may be helpful to be more concise and also provide an example.